# Can anyone identify this red LEGO Technic car set from the late 80's/early 90's?

Tags: set-identification, technic

Kit built a jeep or race car. Roughly from the late 80's/early 90's.

Car had a rear differential, wishbone suspension and rack and pinion steering.

Very similar to http://www.technicopedia.com/8865.html but I don't think they are the same.

Photo in its current state might have modifications from the original plans though.

[image: front view]

[image: back view]

**Update** here's it rebuilt, couldn't be bothered finding some pieces in the correct colours though...

[image: rebuilt front view]

[image: rebuilt rear view]

Comment: Glad to see you were able to reconstruct it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Searching for sets containing both 1x6 technic bricks and 6x10 plates in red quickly yields [set 8865](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8865-1).

[image: Instructions for set 8865]

Note that this set came with instructions for two different builds; you seem to have the remnants of the alternate build (seen on the bottom of the cover for the instructions booklet).

See also the back of the cardboard box from [this eurobricks review](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/76700-review-8865-test-carjeep/):

[image]

Comment: That was as close as I could find too, just since the windscreen/roof was different (possibly modified though) and a few other discrepancies made me wonder if there was a similar kit I didn't see... Thanks for the help!

Comment: Will see how I go rebuilding it now I have the instructions (and hopefully enough of the parts!)